# Use special characters (Umlaut) in Express Response

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express to deliver a file download like this:

```
const fileStream = Storage.getFileStream(path);
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename="${filename}"`);
res.setHeader('Content-type', contentType);
res.setHeader('Content-length', size);
fileStream.pipe(res);
```

When `filename` contains special characters (Ä, Ü, è, ...) an error is thrown, saying I'm using characters that are not allowed.

I found a solution in using [unidecode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unidecode). But is there a solution that keeps an "Ä" instead of converting it to "A"

*I search this issue but I got very confused how to handle this the right way, so forgive me if this question is a duplicate...*

---

Solution (added later): I found this solution that works for me and keeps all special characters in the filename:

```
const filename = encodeURI(file.filename);
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename*=UTF-8''${filename}; filename=${filename}`);
res.setHeader('Content-type', contentType);
res.setHeader('Content-length', size);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may Try Normalizing the string with one of the great library
JavaScript Unicode 8.0 Normalization - NFC, NFD, NFKC, NFKD.
Which can be availed using :-

npm install unorm

An example Code -

```
var unorm = require('unorm');

var text =
  'The \u212B symbol invented by A. J. \u00C5ngstr\u00F6m ' +
  '(1814, L\u00F6gd\u00F6, \u2013 1874) denotes the length ' +
  '10\u207B\u00B9\u2070 m.';

var combining = /[\u0300-\u036F]/g; // Use XRegExp('\\p{M}', 'g'); see 
example.js.

console.log('Regular:  ' + text);
console.log('NFC:      ' + unorm.nfc(text));
console.log('NFD:      ' + unorm.nfd(text));
console.log('NFKC:     ' + unorm.nfkc(text));
console.log('NFKD: *   ' + unorm.nfkd(text).replace(combining, ''));
console.log(' * = Combining characters removed from decomposed form.');
```

Source: https://github.com/walling/unorm
I hope It works.